# null point expression error is crushing the application

Tags: java

Help with this code please am getting errors and my app is crashing.

**Code:**

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_restoration_connect2);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    RootRef.keepSynced ( true );
```

**Exception:**

```
2019-10-25 16:17:14.656 23240-23240/com.example.ezvisa
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ezvisa, PID: 23240
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ezvisa/com.example.ezvisa.RestorationConnect}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a
null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2779)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6368)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object
reference
        at com.example.ezvisa.RestorationConnect.onCreate(RestorationConnect.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6368) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: My guess is FirebaseAuth.getInstance() is returning a null object. Either null check this object or figure out why that returns null

Comment: This might be a nit: you're getting the current user and saving it in a variable then _not_ using that var in the next line.  It'll probably help to check for a null `currentUser` and check the docs for _when_ the return from `getCurrentUser()` may be null and work from there.

Comment: Well it seems that `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It is giving a null pointer exception when trying to get the uid. It is posssible that no user is signed in so put it in a condition block like:

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    String currentUserID = user.getUid();
}
```

The firebase website has also very good documentation in case you want to follow through: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide whether or not you want to allow the creation of this activity while `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` is `null`. You can either prevent the creation or allow it, but in the latter case, you must make sure that your code can deal with the `null`s.